# How to upload file with curl when --data-binary is present in tampered data?

Tags: curl

I try to upload files to a popular website, I tampered the http POST requests with Chrome developer tools' "copy as curl" feature. When the upload begins I get this curl command:

```
curl 'http://example.com/cgi-bin/upload.pl?upload_id=869ab8e228f7bd92bfaebc6d6bf31470' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Referer: http://example.com/upload.php?action=gallery&gid=0&title=My+precious+car' -H 'Origin: http://example.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryAh0xuOK8vajmXWbY' --data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundaryAh0xuOK8vajmXWbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="type"\r\n\r\n1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryAh0xuOK8vajmXWbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="gid"\r\n\r\n0\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryAh0xuOK8vajmXWbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="title"\r\n\r\nMy precious car\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryAh0xuOK8vajmXWbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="resize"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryAh0xuOK8vajmXWbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="private"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryAh0xuOK8vajmXWbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="cat1"\r\n\r\n24\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryAh0xuOK8vajmXWbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="cat2"\r\n\r\n65\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryAh0xuOK8vajmXWbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="cat3"\r\n\r\n13\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryAh0xuOK8vajmXWbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="upfile_0"; filename="1.zip"\r\nContent-Type: application/zip\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryAh0xuOK8vajmXWbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="upfile_1"; filename=""\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryAh0xuOK8vajmXWbY--\r\n' --compressed
```

Or look at here: http://pastebin.com/3Jaj0mSs

When I try to use this from command line (after logging in and getting cookies, and upload_id, etc), file upload progress doesn't start. I have tried to add options to the curl command "-T 1.zip" or "--data-binary @1.zip" or making filename like "<1.zip" but no success, I always get error message: "Send failure: Broken pipe". Filename 1.zip is at the end part of the "--data-binary" section of the long command. What can I do to make curl work in this situation and make the file upload done correctly?

Comment: *"after logging in and getting cookies"* -- Well for starters if logging in sends back cookies that you need to manage, you'd need to send them back with the request. curl, of course, has no knowledge of any cookies that any other applications (e.g. Chrome) have received.

Comment: Yes, I realized that, I pass them always with "-b cookie-file" but still no success...

Answer (score 3):

I looked at it in with Fiddler and the problem is that Chrome erases the file content from the curl request it generates. So you have to insert it back in.

I got it to work with http://www.zippyshare.com/.

Here was the curl request Chrome generated

```
curl "http://www72.zippyshare.com/upload" -H "Origin: http://www.zippyshare.com" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------KM7cH2GI3Ef1gL6GI3ei4Ef1Ij5KM7" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Referer: http://www.zippyshare.com/" -H "Cookie: __utma=46003887.80665104.1404275690.1404275690.1404275690.1; __utmb=46003887.1.10.1404275690; __utmc=46003887; __utmz=46003887.1404275690.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not"%"20provided); ziplocale=en" -H "Proxy-Connection: keep-alive" --data-binary '------------KM7cH2GI3Ef1gL6GI3ei4Ef1Ij5KM7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"

Giant_Panda_Tai_Shan.jpg
------------KM7cH2GI3Ef1gL6GI3ei4Ef1Ij5KM7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadify"

true
------------KM7cH2GI3Ef1gL6GI3ei4Ef1Ij5KM7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="embPlayerValues"

null
------------KM7cH2GI3Ef1gL6GI3ei4Ef1Ij5KM7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filedata"; filename="Giant_Panda_Tai_Shan.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------------KM7cH2GI3Ef1gL6GI3ei4Ef1Ij5KM7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Upload"

Submit Query
------------KM7cH2GI3Ef1gL6GI3ei4Ef1Ij5KM7--' --compressed
```

I divided the data into two pieces where the file was.

Part 1:

```
------------KM7cH2GI3Ef1gL6GI3ei4Ef1Ij5KM7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"

Giant_Panda_Tai_Shan.jpg
------------KM7cH2GI3Ef1gL6GI3ei4Ef1Ij5KM7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadify"

true
------------KM7cH2GI3Ef1gL6GI3ei4Ef1Ij5KM7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="embPlayerValues"

null
------------KM7cH2GI3Ef1gL6GI3ei4Ef1Ij5KM7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filedata"; filename="Giant_Panda_Tai_Shan.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

.
```

(That . wasn't at the end, I added it just now to get the code block to recognize there are two blank lines at the end of the file.)

Part 2:

```
.
Submit Query
------------KM7cH2GI3Ef1gL6GI3ei4Ef1Ij5KM7--
```

(Again with the .)

Also you need to make sure the files are in CRLF format.

Now you can run

```
cat part1.txt Giant_Panda_Tai_Shan.jpg part2.txt > complete
```

Then to run it

```
curl "http://www72.zippyshare.com/upload" -H "Referer: http://www.zippyshare.com/" -H "Origin: http://www.zippyshare.com" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------KM7cH2GI3Ef1gL6GI3ei4Ef1Ij5KM7" --data-binary @complete --compressed
```

It runs (takes a few seconds to upload) and returns html confirming the successful upload.